# Expanding A Console In Windows 10 OS

Tags: c++, windows

**Background Information:** I'm developing an Windows 10 app. Within my app, I'm working with nested consoles. I'm familiar with `GetSystemMetrics()` and using some of it's parameters to define my console physical appearance (i.e. `SM_CXBORDER`, `SM_CXDLGFRAME`, etc).

**Snip:** [Nested Child Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgudY.png)

**Problem:** What parameter should I look into if I want my nested child consoles (i.e. child's child console) to be resizable? My current logic output a user cmd onto this console. Overtime, the outputs accumulate. For example, if a user inputs the cmd `Time` 10 times then he/she will need to start scrolling through the outputs to see any previous output. In the desired scenario, the user can input the cmd `Time` 10 times without having to scroll which can be done by extending the console vertically. As a user, I rather extend the console than scroll through the outputs. This is purely for better visibility and less congestion.

**Attempt:** I tried altering `DLGFRAME`, `DLGWINFRAME`, `RESIZEFRAME`, and `SCROLL`. However, I didn't have much success.

Comment: please read [Window and Screen Buffer Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/window-and-screen-buffer-size)

Answer (score 1):

There is no layout engine in the classic Windows API that will make your window extend size automatically

"Fit window size to text" is a feature that is implemented only in more sophisticated GUI toolkits.

If you insist on using the classic Windows API for your GUI (kind of like using stone age tools) - the only option is to calculate how big your rendered text is going to be (either assume it is always one line or use DrawText with the DT_CALCRECT flag) and extend your main window and text control by that amount.

On the whole you would be far more wise to switch to a real GUI toolkit, than wrestle with WINAPI and reinvent extremely complex wheels

BTW don't call it a console - because console is a term used to refer to Windows console terminals that use a different API - your question is confusing with existing terminology